# Not able to replace column of one table with another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, sql-update

My code is

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
$insert=$membersdb->query("UPDATE members SET  Username=properties.Username FROM members JOIN uidlist on  members.Username=Properties.Username"); echo "Error : ".$membersdb->error."<br>";
if($insert){echo "Done !<br>";}else{echo "Not Done !<br>";

$insert2=$membersdb->query("UPDATE members SET Username=`uidlist.Username'"); echo "Error : ".$membersdb->error."<br>";
if($insert2){echo "Second Insert Done !<br>";}else{echo "Second Insert Also Not Done !<br>";}

$insert3=$membersdb->query("Update members Set Username =(Select uidlist.Username From uidlist) WHERE members.Name=uidlist.Name"); echo "Error : ".$membersdb->error."<br>";
if($insert3){echo "Third Insert Done !<br>";}else{echo "Third Insert  Also Not Done !<br>";}
}
```

I am trying three different queries to replace Username of `members` table with Username of `uidlist` table

The errors are as follows:

> Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM members JOIN uidlist on
>   members.Username=Properties.Username' at line 1 Not Done !
>
> Error : Unknown column 'uidlist.Username' in 'field list' Second
>   Insert Also Not Done !
>
> Error : Unknown column 'uidlist.Name' in 'where clause' Third Insert
>   Also Not Done !

Answer (score 1):

The first statement has the right idea, although the syntax is incorrect, as you noticed. In MySQL, the `join` clause comes before the `set` clause:

```
UPDATE members m
JOIN   uidlist u on m.name = u.name
SET    m.Username = u.Username
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Update syntax does not have a ***FROM*** see any site for reference.
2. `uidlist.Username' this is not correct you should use select statement instead.
3. It is a simple mistake. Your column name is ***uidlist.username*** not ***uidlist.Name***